# Can I convert a Jungle Disk 2.0 bucket to a "compatible" bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, jungledisk

I have some data in a Jungle Disk 2.0 bucket on Amazon S3. It seems like the data in this bucket cannot be accessed via Amazon's own web interface to S3 - at least not very conveniently (the data is there, but the file names and directory structure are not very "friendly").

I would like to convert the bucket to a "compatible" bucket (I believe "compatible" is Jungle Disk's term) so that it is easier to access when not using Jungle Disk Desktop or Web Access.

Or, another good solution for me would be to move the data from the 2.0 bucket to my existing compatible bucket. I know I could do this by downloading the data to desktop and then uploading to the other bucket - looking for a way to do the transfer without a large download/upload, if possible.

Any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and contacted Jungle Disk support directly for this question - just wanted to share the answer:

> The only way would be to map the drives locally and copy from drive to
>   drive.

Oh well...